# how to trigger the event in case of bot restart or crash discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I would like my bot when I restart it or crash it activates an event that deletes momentary data. I tried using `on_disconnect` as an event but it doesn't work. In the code below I used `on_disconnect` as a command but I wish there was an event. It's possible?

```py
async def on_disconnect(ctx):
    cursor = levelsystem_db.cursor()
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM anti_spam WHERE client_id = {str(member.id)}")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(member, member.id, len(result))
        if (len(result) != 0):
            cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM anti_spam WHERE client_id = {str(member.id)}")
            levelsystem_db.commit()
            print(f"ho rimosso i dati di {member}")
```

EDIT:

```py
import discord


class Bot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        discord.Client.__init__(self)
        return

    async def on_ready(self) -> None:
        await self.close()  # This can simulate a crash for now
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Bot()
    client.run(token)
    # Code after crash here
    print('Bot has crashed')
    cursor = levelsystem_db.cursor()
    guild = client.get_guild(637626960599842824)
    print(guild)
    for member in guild.members:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM anti_spam WHERE client_id = {str(member.id)}")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(member, member.id, len(result))
        if (len(result) != 0):
            cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM anti_spam WHERE client_id = {str(member.id)}")
            levelsystem_db.commit()
            print(f"ho rimosso i dati di {member}")
```

Comment: Add code after the section where you call `client.run('TOKEN')` and that will execute when the bot is completely shut off.

Comment: It did not work. Should I use the `on_disconnect` event?

Comment: `on_disconnect` gets called around every 10 minutes because Discord forces bots to "refresh" their connection every so often. I wouldn't recommend putting "final" code there.

Comment: However it doesn't work even if I add the script without event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the bot crashes, you can have code after your `client.run('TOKEN')` that will be executed. For example:

```py
import discord


class Bot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        discord.Client.__init__(self)
        return

    async def on_ready(self) -> None:
        await self.close()  # This can simulate a crash for now
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Bot()
    client.run('TOKEN')

    # Code after crash here
    print('Bot has crashed')
```

With this implementation, you could even call a subprocess that would bring the bot back online.

**Edit (Event Loop Error Fix):**

You will want to import these:

```py
from asyncio import set_event_loop
from asyncio import SelectorEventLoop
from selectors import SelectSelector
```

Then have this line before creating the client:

```py
set_event_loop(SelectorEventLoop(SelectSelector()))
```

Comment: Sorry for the absence. In the end I tried and this only happens if it crashes even though I wish it would happen when I turn it off. The problem is that it gives me this [error](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/806685953425932288/unknown.png) do you know how to fix? The new code I used is above

Comment: To fix that "error", you need to set up a custom asyncio loop for the bot. But it's not really necessary since that "error" is not that big of a deal. I will add the code to fix that just in case though.

Comment: This only works when it crashes right? if I for example want to turn it off voluntarily I should do another command right? And then you did the class just to simulate a possible crash?

Comment: I always run my bot's within a `discord.Client` class, but yes the `await self.close()` code was used to instantly shutdown the bot when it came online. Placing code after `client.run()` will work if the bot crashes or is shutdown manually.

Comment: in this moment I have removed the class since I don't use them but if I stop voluntarily the message doesn't appear. If I do this with the class added to simulate it just takes me one user (the bot) and then doesn't continue the `for` loop ([console](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/806703111417626661/unknown.png))